# Using Google Analytics without importing the snippet

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics, analytics, google-analytics-api

In my current job I have to import an analytics framework into our clients pages (we're a 3rd party also, our services are provided by including our tag in the client's pages) for counting basic metrics such as: Visitors,Visits,Views,Avg. Visit duration,Bounce Rate,Pages/Visit .

I've looked at several opensource solution such as piwik etc.. but as we handle allot of traffic this will come at a pretty hefty price, so obviously GA seems like the most reasonable solution for us. the problem is that the bulk of my clients already have GA on their pages and everybody has a different version of it (analytics.js,ga.js,dc.js etc..) where each version has a different method of working with multiple trackers on page and some don't support that all together. so using a pixel reporting technique seems like the safest method to use here but .. I can't find any documentation on google or anywhere else for that matter explaining what functionality I will loose when using this approach.

The [API documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference) does a decent job of showing me how to do it myself and there's also [nojsstats](http://nojsstats.blogspot.co.il/2009/09/free-google-analytics-without.html) (which i prefer not to use) but has anyone had any experience with this kind of a scenario and can eloborate on what functionality will be lost as a result of this approach? or has found a different solution for this kind of problem?

Thanks in advance, 
Amnon

Answer (score 0):

You can look into the p[arameter reference for the measurement protocol](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters) - that's what you can get, provided you pass all the parameters (so everything that's not in there you lose, most notably all Geo information which will be set to the location of your server).

The biggest challenge would be that you'd have to maintain a session id in your respective clients applications, else you'll only register single page visits with 100% bounce rate (since Google will not know which visits belong to the same user). That seems a lot more cumbersome than additional javascript trackers.

However since they already have Google Analytics you do not need to implement any tracker at all, you can query the existing accounts via a serverside language of your choice (or via Google Apps Script). Which is actually what the documentation you've linked to describes (Core reporting API is not about collecting data, but about querying existing data).